# sphinx not to include source code during build

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to document my python packages using Sphinx 1.2.1.

My definition of the rst file contains some description about each modules, usage and adding the autodoc syntax for restructured text as below.

```
module
------

.. automodule:: RAT.REPORTER.bemrstcreator
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

The above setup makes a clear html build for me without any problem. It derives the docs from all the class, its associated members etc., but it includes the source code in the html. How can I indicate sphinx not to link the source code of each module?

Comment: A guess: you need to disable the [sphinx.ext.viewcode](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/viewcode.html) extension.

Comment: Thanks. Just remove it from the extension in conf.py. Worked well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the conf.py where make all modifications with regards to specific documentation remove the sphinx.ext.viewcode extension.

```
# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'rst2pdf.pdfbuilder'
]
```

The above was modified to

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'rst2pdf.pdfbuilder'
]
```

Answer (score 16):

You can find the next configuration value, on the `config.py` file, and set it to false:

```
html_show_sourcelink = False
```